# Mouse click detection in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I have a task, where I have a square 3X3 and for every click in the small square, this square will paint in red. Here is my code yet. I think I did something wrong in my first while loop, but I'm not sure. Please help me.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

#create a screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

#colors
white = [255, 255, 255]
red = [255, 0, 0]

x = 0
y = 0

#create my square
for j in range(3):

    for i in range(3):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, (x, y, 30, 30), 1)
        x += 30

        if x == 90:
            x = 0
            y += 30

pygame.display.flip()
running = 1

while running:

    event = pygame.event.poll()

#found in what position my mouse is
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = 0
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        print("mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

#mouse click
    if click[0] == 1 and x in range(30) and y in range (30):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (30, 30 , 29 ,29))

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pygame.display.change()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `update` your screen each time when you draw or do something in screen. So, put this line under your first while loop.

```
pygame.display.flip()
```

In your condition you was checking x and y and which are not mouse position.

```
if click[0] == 1 and x in range(30) and y in range (30):
```

Check your mouse position in `range(90)` because of you have three rectangular and the are `30x30`.

```
if click[0] == 1 and mouse[0] in range(90) and mouse[1] in range (90):
```

Then, set your rectangular start position to fill the mouse point.

```
rect_x = 30*(mouse[0]//30) # set start x position of rectangular  
rect_y = 30*(mouse[1]//30) # set start y position of rectangular
```

You can edit your code with this.

```
while running:

    pygame.display.flip()
    event = pygame.event.poll()

    #found in what position my mouse is
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = 0
    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        print("mouse at (%d, %d)" % event.pos)


    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    #mouse click
    if click[0] == 1 and mouse[0] in range(90) and mouse[1] in range (90):

        '''
        rect_x = 30*(0//30) = 0
        rect_y = 30*(70//30) = 60
        '''

        rect_x = 30*(mouse[0]//30) # set start x position of rectangular  
        rect_y = 30*(mouse[1]//30) # set start y position of rectangular 

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (rect_x, rect_y , 30 , 30)) # rectangular (height, width), (30, 30)
```

[image]